# Using Front Camera in Vuforia Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to create an AR experience that works with both front and rear cameras (where available). I want to switch between them just like you would with a default camera app.

Does Vuforia Framework Support Front Camera, and does someone integrate Vuforia with other face tracking AR framework before and how was the experience ?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Vuforia front camera setting]

In your AR camera settings, you will find this option ranging from CAMERA_DEFAULT, CAMERA_BACK and CAMERA_FRONT.

To access the camera via script, Vuforia has explained in detail in this page:
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-the-Camera

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool lightOn = false;
    private bool frontCamera = false;

    public void CameraChange()
    {
        if (!frontCamera)
        {
            RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
            frontCamera = true;
            Debug.Log("Using Front Camera");
        }
        else if (frontCamera)
        {
            RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
            frontCamera = false;
            Debug.Log("Using Back Camera");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera status available.");
        }
    }

    private void RestartCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection newDir)
    {
        CameraDevice.Instance.Stop();
        CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit();
        CameraDevice.Instance.Init(newDir);
        CameraDevice.Instance.Start();

        // Periodically check to see if still needed
        VuforiaUnity.OnPause();
        VuforiaUnity.OnResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is deprecated in vuforia version 8.1.7

Comment: Yes unfortunately, I am using v7.2.24. Perhaps use this to access the feature.

Comment: how can i downgrade Vuforia version safely to 7.2.24 , i am currently using version 8.1.7

Comment: The only way to do this would be to uninstall the current version of Unity that you are using and then install it again with the vuforia checked from install components. This will install the 7th version of vuforia.

Comment: My recommendation would be to always use Unity hub while installing different versions of Unity.

Comment: Mark the answer if it helped you. I have added the script as well that will help you in achieving what you wanted.

Comment: sure it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia has deprecated the front camera in his newer versions (8.x and newers).

You can use older versions of unity to force use vuforia 7.x

In my case, I used Unity 2018.2.12 and downloaded vuforia 7 here:

[Vuforia-AR-Support-for-Editor-2018.2.12f1.exe](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/0a46ddfcfad4/TargetSupportInstaller/UnitySetup-Vuforia-AR-Support-for-Editor-2018.2.12f1.exe)