# How to switch mobile camera in Vuforia Engine Unity SDK v10.13?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I need help in switching mobile device camera in sdk Vuforia Engine Unity SDK v10.13 because vuforia has chnages the entire SDk. I did it past but i could find any documentation. Please help

I couldn't find any documention regarding camera switching in Vuforia Engine Unity SDK v10.13

Comment: note that device front camera use has been deprecated in Vuforia since 8.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648527/using-front-camera-in-vuforia-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately switching btw back and front camera has been depracated but this can be achieved if its necessary via https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/driver-framework.

If you need to sw btw the several back cameras that phones have, I don't believe its necessary as Vuforia usually selects the main camera and selecting any other camera like Telephoto or Ultrawide will results in tracking issues as the SDK was not designed to work with such images out of the box.

The Q that I would have, why do you need to sw? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: To answer your question, we can do many things by switching between the world camera and the face camera. As a developer, we have to do things which is required by the client.